# Page scrolls up on clicking a link in landscape mode of Windows phone

Tags: html, windows-phone

I'm creating webpages using **HTML** for windows phone. The issue is that clicking on a link the page scrolls up.

I have tried **preventDefault** and return `false`..

Both the solutions works fine on **portrait view** but in **landscape view** the problem still exists.

```
$(".menu dt a").click(function(e) {
            // Hide selection area
        var divParent = document.getElementById($(this).parent().attr("id"));
        if (divParent.getElementsByTagName('dd')[0].getElementsByTagName('ul')[0].style.display == "block")
        {
            divParent.getElementsByTagName('dd')[0].getElementsByTagName('ul')[0].style.display = "none";
        }
        else
        {
            divParent.getElementsByTagName('dd')[0].getElementsByTagName('ul')[0].style.display = "block";
        }

        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Comment: Welcome on StackOverflow! Can you post us some code so we can look at it?

Comment: There was some problem with css. The problem has got solved.